# Mocha/Chai to.not.throw(TypeError) strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I try to do unit testing on NodeJs with Mocha & Chai...

My first test suite is to verify if a constructor function return or does not return TypeError depending on parameters type.

```js
/* ./test/entity/Point.js */

"use strict";

var expect = require("chai").expect;
var Point = require("./../entity/Point");

describe("Point entity", function() {
    it("x parameter must not be string", function() {
        var fn = function() { var p = new Point("5", 40); };
        expect(fn).to.throw(TypeError);
    });

    it("y parameter must not be string", function() {
        var fn = function() { var p = new Point(5, "40"); };
        expect(fn).to.throw(TypeError);
    });

    it("x and y parameters must be number", function() {
        var fn = function() { var p = new Point(5, 40); };
        expect(fn).to.not.throw(TypeError);
    });
});
```

The constructor function that i test :

```js
/*./entity/Point.js */

"use strict";

function Point(x, y) {
    // Type validation
    if(x && !(typeof x === "number")) {
        throw new TypeError("x is expected to be a number");
    }
    if(y && !(typeof y === "number")) {
        throw new TypeError("y is expected to be a number");
    }

    // instantiation
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

module.exports = Point;
```

First test is ok.
Second test is ok.
But third test send me a strange assertion error :

```
  Point entity
    V x parameter must not be string
    V y parameter must not be string
    1) x and y parameters must be number


  2 passing (67ms)
  1 failing

  1) Point entity x and y parameters must be number:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to not throw 'TypeError' but 'TypeError: Point is not a function' was thrown

      at Context. (C:\Users\Cedric\Documents\NodeProjects\SqueezeParking\test\entity\Point.js:19:32)
      at callFn (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:326:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:319:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
      at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
      at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
      at next (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

If i used NodeJs assert module instead of Chai, i also get an assertion error :

```
  Point entity
    V x parameter must not be string
    V y parameter must not be string
    1) x and y parameters must be number


  2 passing (55ms)
  1 failing

  1) Point entity x and y parameters must be number:
     AssertionError: Got unwanted exception (TypeError)..
      at _throws (assert.js:341:5)
      at Function.assert.doesNotThrow (assert.js:359:3)
      at Context. (C:\Users\Cedric\Documents\NodeProjects\SqueezeParking\test\entity\Point.js:19:16)
      at callFn (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:326:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:319:7)
      at Runner.runTest (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
      at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:528:12
      at next (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
      at C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
      at next (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Cedric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

If i use Chai or NodeJs assert module outside Mocha, third test don't throw TypeError :

```js
/*./server.js */

var expect = require("chai").expect;
var Point = require("./entity/Point");
var fn = function() {
    var p = new Point(10, 20);
}
expect(fn).to.not.throw(TypeError);
```

It seems that this strange TypeError come from Mocha but i don't understand why and how...
Do someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test code is importing itself as a module. To illustrate, change you code at the start of `./test/entity/Point.js` to this:

```
exports.foo = "foo";
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var Point = require("./../entity/Point");
console.log(Point);
```

And you'll get the output:

```
{ foo: 'foo' }
[... followed by the tests passing and failing ...]
```

Change the path you use to require the code you want to test to `var Point = require("../../entity/Point");` and your tests will pass.

Comment: Oh my god! I am ashamed of myself!
Thanks for your help @Louis.